# How to close current page window when button clicked in visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Its working, when preview button clicks page will be open and close button clicks its working. but i copied page url and paste in another tab, close button clicks its not working.

```
<apex:page> 
   <apex:form>
      <apex:commandbutton onClick="window.top.close();" value="Close"  />
    </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript can only close a window *opened* by JavaScript. This is a security feature. You can read more about that on [MDN's Window.close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close):

> In the past, when you called the window object's close() method directly, rather than calling close() on a window instance, the browser closed the frontmost window, whether your script created that window or not. This is no longer the case; for security reasons, scripts are no longer allowed to close windows they didn't open. (Firefox 46.0.1: scripts can not close windows, they had not opened)